# Relative path for video.js (video-js) flash swf

Tags: video.js

Why does video-js setup guide use an absolute path to refer to video-js.swf and not a relative path?

```
<link href="//example.com/path/to/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//example.com/path/to/video.js"></script>
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://example.com/path/to/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

The setup guide offers no explanation!

Answer (score 1):

That would seem to be an inconsistency. You should [submit a bug](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/new).

The main library urls use protocol-relative URLs to avoid security issues, and the swf should probably be the same.